# how to select particular columns in sql statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, dataset

i need to drop columns which has value '0' in both the rows

```
select  DateString as 'Date',machine, 
sum (case when vfrm.job_id = '105' then (total_hours) else '0' end)as A,           
sum (case when vfrm.job_id = '100' then (total_hours) else '0' end) as B,        
sum (case when vfrm.job_id = '101' then (total_hours) else '0' end) as C,         
sum (case when vfrm.job_id = '102' then (total_hours) else '0' end) as D,          
sum (case when vfrm.job_id = '103' then (total_hours) else '0' end) as E,              
sum (case when vfrm.job_id = '134' then (total_hours) else '0'  end) as F,             
sum (case when vfrm.job_id = '135' then (total_hours) else '0' end) as G ,
sum (case when vfrm.job_id = '9995' then (total_hours) else '0' end) as OTHERS     
 from    ven_fullreportmaster vfrm                    
             INNER JOIN ven_descriptionmaster VDM ON VDM.description_id = vfrm..description_id                    
             inner join ven_machinemaster vm on  vm.machine_id = vfrm..machine_id        
             inner join ven_jobcodemaster vjm on vjm.job_id = vfrm.job_id            
             inner join Dim_Time dt on dt.Date_Id = vfrm.date_id                  
             where  vfrm.entry_date = '20111208'                   
                     and  vfrm.shift_id =2     
                     and vfrm.description_id in (1,3,5)     
                     and vfrm.job_id not in (9999,9998,9996,9994)                              
                     and vjm.job_status ='ACTIVE'                      
    group by   description_name, DateString
```

### output:

[image]
please help me out to solve this issue..

Regards

T.Navin

### updated:

i am saving the above sql query result into an data set in c#..
is it possible to filter the columns which contains '0' in both the rows..so that the dataset looks like required output in the snap shot

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. You have to store the result from your query in a temp table and then use the temp table to build a dynamic query against it, only including the columns that does not have a 0 in all rows. With a dynamic number of columns in the result set you have to build a query dynamically. Perhaps this is easier to do in some client code instead?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: thanx.. i will try to do it dynamically.. i am storing the output in a dataset in c#, is it possible to filter the coloumns in the dataset like the required output in the snapshot

Comment: I don't know enough C# to be able to answer that. I'm sure there are ways of hiding columns in presentation. If it is best done in the dataset or in some GUI component I can't tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have filtered my dataset which are having '0' in the columns..
i ref this site , to get the output

http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/08/11/removing-columns-in-datatable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something that is best left to a reporting tool like SQL Server Reporting Services, Crystal Reports, etc.  However, if it needs to get done and you are not using a reporting tool then it is at least possible.

On the C# side you might be able to remove the columns from the underlying DataTable in the DataSet by cycling through the Columns collection of the DataTable.  This would require looking at both rows for each field (or using a Linq query) and then removing the Column.  I have not tried this so I am not sure of the effectiveness of it or how easy/complicated it would be.  You can find more details about the DataTable structure here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns.aspx

If you have the option of calling a Stored Procedure, you can do the multi-step operation that @Mikael suggested in the first comment on the question.  Here is how I would approach this from the T-SQL side:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempResults ([Date] VARCHAR(30), Machine VARCHAR(50),
    [A] INT, [B] INT, [C] INT, [D] INT, [E] INT, [F] INT, [G] INT,
    [OTHERS] INT)

INSERT INTO #TempResults ([Date], Machine, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, OTHERS)
    SELECT  DateString AS [Date],
            machine, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '105' THEN (total_hours) ELSE '0' END) AS [A],
        SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '100' THEN (total_hours) ELSE '0' END) AS [B],
        SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '101' THEN (total_hours) ELSE '0' END) AS [C],
        SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '102' THEN (total_hours) ELSE '0' END) AS [D],
        SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '103' THEN (total_hours) ELSE '0' END) AS [E],
        SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '134' THEN (total_hours) ELSE '0'  END) AS [F],
        SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '135' THEN (total_hours) ELSE '0' END) AS [G],
        SUM(CASE WHEN vfrm.job_id = '9995' THEN (total_hours) ELSE '0' END) AS [OTHERS]
    FROM    ven_fullreportmaster vfrm
    INNER JOIN  ven_descriptionmaster vdm
            ON  vdm.description_id = vfrm.description_id
    INNER JOIN  ven_machinemaster vm
            ON  vm.machine_id = vfrm.machine_id
    INNER JOIN  ven_jobcodemaster vjm
            ON  vjm.job_id = vfrm.job_id
    INNER JOIN  Dim_Time dt
            ON  dt.Date_Id = vfrm.date_id
    WHERE   vfrm.entry_date = '20111208'
    AND     vfrm.shift_id = 2
    AND     vfrm.description_id IN (1, 3, 5)
    AND     vfrm.job_id NOT IN (9999, 9998, 9996, 9994)
    AND     vjm.job_status = 'ACTIVE'
    GROUP BY    description_name, DateString

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT [Date], Machine, '

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TempResults WHERE [A] > 0))
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'[A], '
END

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TempResults WHERE [B] > 0))
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'[B], '
END

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TempResults WHERE [C] > 0))
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'[C], '
END

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TempResults WHERE [D] > 0))
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'[D], '
END

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TempResults WHERE [E] > 0))
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'[E], '
END

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TempResults WHERE [F] > 0))
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'[F], '
END

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TempResults WHERE [G] > 0))
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + N'[G], '
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + N'[OTHERS] FROM #TempResults'

EXEC (@SQL)
GO
```

P.S. There seems to be an issue with your GROUP BY clause as I would expect the [Machine] field to be required in it.

Comment: thanx..i am off today, i will check this query tomorrow and  i will let u know d result :) ..